# How to bind the mouse

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i wish bind the mouse icon in a Visual Brush,i.e i have a Canvas and so i add  A visual Brush to bind whole content of the Canvas but now i wish bind also when the mouse move the Visual Brush can reproduce the movement of the mouse into the Canvas.
Do you have any idea how work out this step/feature?
Thanks so much.

ahh i forget i wish develop this feature in WPF

Cheers

EDIT:
Maybe im not clear to explain my request so i will link a webpage that recreate the same effect [Example](http://www.chromazone-imaging.co.uk/flashindex.html)

here you can understand better infact i wish reproduce the same effect of the mouse binding in a small window and when the mouse move in the main window the shape in the small window will follow its movement.

Sorry my English is not good.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitsu Furuta has a good example of how to do it in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/mitsu/archive/2009/03/09/wpf-surface-demo-driving-an-extending-desktop-with-a-popfly-duck.aspx). Just skip the part about Surface and the popfly duck ;)